# Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: .net, asp.net, custom-error-pages, server-error

When I am running my application,I am getting this error.(Server Error in '/' Application Object reference not set to an instance of an object).I don't know why I am getting this error. I searched on the net, people are saying to off customerror in webconfig. Does it right way to find out it?

Comment: Post stack trace or follow the instructions on the error page you see how to enable its displaying (`customError=false`)

Comment: this is a very general asp.net error. we definately need more info to be able to help u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to need more information than just this to resolve this error.

This article shows how to show the full error messages:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y123fsf7(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.remotingconfiguration.customerrorsenabled(v=vs.85).aspx

This will then show you the full error you are getting.

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It basically means you're accessing a `null` object.  It is impossible for us to tell you where it is.  As Curt suggests, you can turn on error checking.  Better yet, attach Visual Studio to the web server (assuming you can) and you should see where the null-reference is getting accessed.

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace the files of bin folder. It will solve the error.

Files generally stored at bin folder:

SolutionName.dll and SolutionName.pdb